# useState() react state variable doesn't re-renders. Any POV?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I need some input on React. I have this code block. As per my understanding the after setStateX(copy), the whole component re-renders. But in my case, it's not happening. Any reason for that?

```
const [stateX, setStateX] = useState([]);

const addAnotherComponent = (e) => {​
    let copy = stateX;
    copy.push(
        <AnotherComponent/>
    );
    setStateX(copy);
  }​;
```

Comment: `let copy = stateX;` copy is __not__ a copy of `stateX`, that's why it doesn't rerender.

Comment: Also storing components in state is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Any suggestion on how should I tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

because you mutate the state and the component doesnt re-render
you first should clone state
let copy=[...stateX]

let updatedState =
[...copy,yourcomponent]

setStateX(updatedState)

Comment: I'd suggest explaining why we should clone. With React, we need to use the method returned from useState to update the array. No need to copy `stateX`. They can just `setStateX([...stateX, <AnotherComponent/>])`. Although, like Brian says, we don't normally store components in React state. Maybe it would be better to instead store the content that goes inside AnotherComponent in the array, like an array of strings. Then use Array.prototype.map to display the array in JSX.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).